# Adding a new element in a column based on a value of another column in R

Tags: r

I have 2 csv files. The first file has the name of countries in the 1st column, year as the second and some other attributes. The second csv file I have contain in 1 column again countries and in the 2nd column the region. I want in the 1st csv file to create a new column where depending on the country to append the right region. It should be noted that the 2 csv files do not have the same number of countries. The 1st one has like 150 and the second has more. Is there a command I can use or I have to do it via for loop?   For example

csv 1

```
Countries  Year ... (other columns)
Greece     2015 ...
Denmark    2015 ...  
Mexico     2015 ..
```

csv 2

```
Countries  Region  ...                   (other columns)
Greece     Western Europe                  ...
Denmark    Western Europe                  ...  
Mexico     Latin America and Caribbean     ...
```

so my final csv file I want it to be like

```
Countries  Year ...  (other columns) ...        Region
Greece     2015 ...                  ...        Western Europe
Denmark    2015 ...                  ...        Western Europe
Mexico     2015 ...                  ...        Latin America and Caribbean
```

Comment: Have you tried `dplyr::left_join()`? assuming the matching country names in column `Countries` in each dataset are exactly the same.

Comment: `merge(countries1, countries2, by = "Countries", all = TRUE)`